# Trying to get the DISTINCT values of 3 columns in sqlite db

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

SO I have a table with 3 cols:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
 a       b     c
 b       c    null
 a      null   b
 c       d     a
```

And my desired output will be:

```
a,b,c,d,null
```

I am hoping to have the output in a single string if possible.

I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3 FROM table
```

and didn't get the desired results.  Any Ideas?

Comment: How can you put NULL in a single string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Col1
FROM table
UNION
SELECT Col2
FROM table
UNION
SELECT Col3
FROM table
```

Comment: `UNION` already removes duplicates. `UNION ALL` does not. No need for the `DISTINCT` here.

Answer (score 2):

A single-string solution (see on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/81225/2)):

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(c, 'NULL'), ',')
FROM    (
        SELECT  col1 c
        FROM    mytable
        UNION
        SELECT  col2 c
        FROM    mytable
        UNION
        SELECT  col3 c
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
```

Comment: Missing the 'null' in the output, no?

Answer (score 1):

does this work in sqlite:

```
select col1 from table 
union
select col2 from table
union 
select coll3 from table
```

or:

```
select col1 from table where col1 is not null
union
select col2 from table where col2 is not null
union 
select coll3 from table where col3 is not null
```

to eliminate nulls.

Note i don't think this would be fast to execute but I know in mssql union will do a distinct on the results

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql, you could use this solution:

```
select group_concat(coalesce(c,'null') order by c is null, c)
from (
  select col1 c from tbl
  union
  select col2 c from tbl
  union
  select col3 c from tbl
) u
```

Union query selects all values, removing all duplicates. I'm then returning the result in a single string, ordered by value with null value at the end, and converting null to 'null' (since group_concat would ignore null values).

If you are using SQLite, Group_Concat doesn't support order by, and you could use this:

```
select group_concat(coalesce(c,'null'))
from (
  select col1 c, col1 is null o from mytable
  union
  select col2 c, col2 is null o from mytable
  union
  select col3 c, col3 is null o from mytable
  order by o, c
) u
```

Comment: sure, you just haven't mentioned this in your answer.